# deja-dup - как запретить копирование скрытых файлов и каталогов

Tags: linux, администрирование

Еженедельно автоматически запускается *deja-dup* для резервирования моего домашнего каталога. Файл исключений для копирования выглядит как-то так:

```
~/.**
~/tmp
~/bin
~/Документы/802.16

. . .
```

Каталоги, которые прописаны явно, вроде *~/tmp* исключаются из копирования, как я и указал. А вот со скрытыми папками - плохо. Маска не работает. А среди скрытых каталогов есть, к примеру, кэши firefox - очень большие!

Я пробовал задавать и ~/.** и ~/.* не работает!

Вопрос: как исключить из копирования deja-dup скрытые папки файлы?

Comment: Чё-нить типа `~/\.mozilla`, `~/\.*`?

Comment: @donRumata В том-то и проблема, что "типа"... В руководстве по программе написано, что она поддерживает "типа" регулярные выражения... Хотя - не совсем :-( Точку "эскейпить" я пробовал. И гадать можно до второго пришествия, что они имели в виду.

Comment: Как вариант - поменять систему бэкапов. У нас главный админ бэкапит свой домашний серв `borgbackup`. Можно ещё в сторону `urbackup` глянуть.

Comment: @donRumata Спасибо. Похоже, что придётся что-то решать.